# Unexpected <br> at start of php file requested by ajax

Tags: php, ajax

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
?>
<root>
    <text>
```

This is my code in the very begining of the file, but response after an ajax call looks like

```
<br>
<root>
    <text>
```

Can anyone explain me what's happening? ( `<br>` bothers me because i can't start a session after any output).

EDIT:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/chat-handling/readMessages.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        conv_id: id,
        act: "display"
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);

    }
});
```

Comment: Do you include any files? It's text somewhere in your code.

Comment: no, that is the begining as i said

Comment: How do you request this file?

Comment: show all your code including ajax

Comment: Maybe you have a character before your opening `<?php` that your editor doesn't pick up on. Put your cursor at the beginning of the file and hit delete. If it looks like nothing is removed you have / had an unwanted character there.

Comment: made that thousand times

Comment: And if you delete <?php ... ?> then <br> vanishes?

Comment: what does readMessages.php looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody, but now i opened it in NetBeans (before i viewed it in Notepad) and i found a ˙ character at the beginning, which caused a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP settings may automatically start a session:
http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

In this case, you might get a warning when calling session_start().
You can try to suppress this warning by using the @

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) @session_start();
?>
<root>
    <text>
```

Comment: ...why do you think the $_SESSION check is there in the first place? :p -- anyway, i check for session by if(!session_id()) , but i guess isset() would work too

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.post("ajaxfile.php",
            {
    conv_id: "id",
    act: "display"
},
        function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
        });


    });

</script>
```

I tried its giving perfect answer

Comment: I can see that this answer has been downvoted. Could someone please point out the problem with the answer so I can improve it?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, just saw this from the review queue as someone also flagged as Low Quality. I'm guessing the issue is because you just posted a load of code with no explanation as to what it does, why the OP should use it, how it solves their problem, etc.

Comment: I checked the code in my pc and its working fine there is no <br> tag coming

Comment: So start with that. "I have tested this code and it works and should resolve your answer because... X does Y..." ;)

Comment: It also works on my computer, but now i'm going on a webhost for my page and it isn't working

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: your file is part of some framework that does something equivalent of

```
ob_start();
include(your_file.php);
echo nl2br(ob_get_clean());
```